# Android 'softInputMethod:adjustResize' not working

Tags: android

Everytime I open `soft keyboard` in my activity, it's hiding some of the control 
elements like the exit chat button and the `recyclerview`.
I have tried many things but it doesn't seem to work.

this is my activity layout XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exitChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryAnonymose"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="leave chat"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/statusBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:checked="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:text="user "
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reyclerview_message_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3.98"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_chatbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:background="#ffffff"

        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chatbox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="write something.."
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,NestedWeights" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="SEND"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpUsage" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In my Menifest file:

```
         <activity
            android:name=".ChatRoomActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

in my activity :

> getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

thanks for the help.

Comment: try modifying  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Answer (score 0):

`adjust_resize` causes your rootview be smaller. In this case, the LinearLayout which holds exit chat button become very small, due to         `android:layout_weight="0.01"`.
To prevent this, you may need to do following action:
- Your root layout should change to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and put your root layout inside ScrollLayout.
- Try to avoid the `android:layout_weight`. If possible, place all items inside RelativeLayout. The RecyclerView may be `layout_above` the chat exit holder, and `layout_below` the send button.

Comment: can you explain to me again more explicitly what it the layouts hierarchy?I am a little bit confused.